# SQL FOR XML attribute & value

Tags: sql, xml

I've been searching for quite some hours now to generate this line of XML from an sql query.
Never needed to include both a value and an attribute in one 'FOR XML' line.
Many thanks for the help.

```
    <Amount Ccy=”EUR”>100.20</Amount>
```

Comment: I take it that the CCY is a column on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT 
   CCY as "Amount/@CCY", 
   Amount, 
   null
FROM <db.schema.tablename>
WHERE  conditions for xml path
```